# How to catch properties binding error in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

i'm currently working on a little application with springBoot and got a configuration class like this :

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationExample {

    @Value("${some.property}")
    private String  myProperty;
}
```

I'm not passing this value with the application.properties file but directly while launching the app

```
java -jar myApp.jar --some.property="Hello"
```

if i don't call the '--some.property="Hello"' it result on a big java error

I wanted to know if there is a way to catch this? In order to be able to print a clearer message

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The value binding happening at the run time(`When Application start`). If you forget pass then `Application context initialization will fail`.

**This is application start issue**

Better to use as below.

```
environment.gerProperty("key");
```

And add `global exception handler` and throw customized exception of value null.

Answer (score 0):

if property does not exists and you still want to load application context
then you can do something like this

```
@Value("${some.property=: #{null}}")
private String some;
```